# Geocoding API vs Geocoder

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-geocoding-api

In my application I need to use the geocoding, but I am not quite clear which method to use. Until yesterday I added the parameters to the URL `maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=myparameter&sensor=false`, but Google blocked my requests for a day, making the application crash because it did not return any results from the request for geocoding.

Now I am using the `Geocoder` class that does the same thing and also I have seen that you can create and use an API key for Geocoding.
Which method do you recommend to use? What is the difference between the two methods, apart from the limitations of the requests?

Answer (score 4):

Geocoder is a built-in API in the Android framework that is free. Geocoding API is a rest API that is paid. Geocoder uses a different search stack internally and this leads to different results comparing to the Geocoding rest API. The Geocoding rest API works better than Geocoder normally but has usage limits and the implementation is bigger.

Comment: Note that the built-in API isn't necessarily available, you would have to have a fallback.

Answer (score 3):

[Geocoder API](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/location/Geocoder) is built into the system and it's easy to use. From my experience, it's working in most cases, although:

- in some cases it fails and throws `grpc failed` IOException

```
       Non-fatal Exception: java.io.IOException: grpc failed
       at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
```

- it may not be even available on some devices (use `isPresent()` method to verify this).

With above, I don't think Geocoder API is super reliable, so if geocoding is a critical part of your app, you may look into other options (like Google's Geocoding API, which is not free).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use a map in your app, you should use the API called: Google Maps Android API v2.

If you need to manage geocoded data (address to lat/lng or viceversa) then enable Geocoding API and start using the class Geocoder.

For example (lat/lng to address):

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(gps.getLatitude(),  gps.getLongitude(), 1);
```

Comment: But the Geocoder class has some limitations? How do you connect the Geocoder class with the Geocode API, must you put the key in the Manifest as for the use of the map?

Comment: No, you just need to enable the API from google console and then you can start using it. In the Manifest.xml you only need to set:          <meta-data 
             android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
       android:value="YOUR key"/>
     <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: @AndreaMontanari Is it needed to define API key, if I will not specify what will happen?

Comment: @NigamPatro basically without API KEY you won't be able to use the service. It's a kind of certificate to let Google know that you are using that specific API

Comment: @AndreaMontanari But, If I am executing that API in my browser without API key then also, its giving result.

Comment: @NigamPatro We are talking about an **android** app, this means that without API key your final users won't be able to use the service outside of the debug session

Comment: @AndreaMontanari Thanks. Let me check.

Answer (score 0):

Users of free API have following limits:

- 2,500 requests per 24 hour period.
- 5 requests per second.

You can include API key in web-request also like:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=API_KEY
```

Not sure about android Geocoder class, maybe someone else can help you out in that matter. But i assume same limits would apply.

Comment: But, basically, while accessing the API without giving any key in browser, it works fine and gives result. So, is it always required to give the key?