# Geocoder vs Geocoding API

Tags: android, google-geocoder, reverse-geocoding

I am working on an app which required to tell the user location for example street#3,baker street ,,,,,london etc , for this king of purpose I am using the geocoder class which sometimes returns null and some times returns me the pure good address. I am doing this as follow :

```
geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
 geocoder.getFromLocation(gps.getLatitude(), gps.longitude, 1);
```

As some of the time I am getting the null in address so some one adviced me to use the following link and pass jus the lat and long of location

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=0000.00,000000
>   I searched it on internet and i got the link of google api that is geocoding class. [google geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) which has some limitations.

so now I am stuck here. I do not want to use the geocoding api as it has some limitations and also as I am lazy i do not want the complex work of api key and also the fetching address from json. :P

so what is best and good for me , and what is recommended. ?

please
 answer me. I got the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858426/geocoding-api-vs-geocoder) but the answer is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will always be query limits with these sorts of web services. The limitation I have experienced with the Service (on JavaScript) is that the **time in between queries without getting `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` increases with the more requests at a time**. The API does not have this setback, so I prefer that. Since the API involves only a URL, I would probably prefer to do that, myself.

So even though there is a query limit for the API, the JavaScript API has a query limit, too, and is a *lot* slower for big batches of data.

Comment: are you talking about this api ? 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=0000.00,000000

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Be careful to make the numbers for latitude and longitude in the correct range; I see that there are 4 0's followed by 2 .0's, and the other one has no decimal point.

Comment: I just posted the demo lati and long

Comment: so in your opinion this link is safe to use ?

Comment: The link is safe; you just need to change the parameters. An example would be: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=36.98934,-80.34853

Comment: so I need to make the http post resquest for this ? and also please tell me for this link do I need to make the api key ?

Comment: You _should_ make a key for it. It doesn't cost anything (if you stay under the query limit, which is pretty high). It is actually just pulling the text off of the page of a url that you need to do. You can see the output data by opening the link I posted, as an example.

Comment: Please just look up the API documentation on Google. It will probably answer most of your questions.

Comment: I know it is , but I am afraid as there could be many user of this app and this app may request many times to this link , so would it not exceed the limit that discussed by the google in using this api ?

Comment: The query limit is something like 2,500 each day. I doubt that Google Maps would record _every single one_, so probably between 2,800 and 3,000. For now don't worry about it. If anything, you can change it later if it becomes a problem. Or if you have thousands of users a day, maybe it is time to start paying for that service....

Comment: can you see my another question and help me there too ?

Comment: Where is the link to it?

Comment: here is my question , the main problem of me in this is that , if i removed the current fragment with the new button How can I access its content such as button or map  in the same activity? link is as below
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010095/how-to-use-multiple-fragment-in-single-activity-in-different-times/31012082#31012082